# CSS - Flexbox div match height of another div

Tags: html, css, flexbox

```css
.d1 {
  display: flex;
}

.d2 {
  flex: 1;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.d3 {
  background-color: lightblue;
  margin: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="d1">
  <div class="d2">
    <div class="d3">Test1</div>
    <div class="d3">Test2</div>
  </div>
  <div class="d2">
    <div class="d3">Test3</div>
    <div class="d3">Test4<br>Test4</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

In the above code, I have two columns of the same width and 2 `div`s in each one. But the 4th `div`, where `Test4<br>Test4` is written, is as a result higher than the others. How can I make the 2nd `div`'s height to always match the 4th? Ty

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Just give `height: 100%;` to the second div using CSS.

```css
.d1 {
  display: flex;
}

.d2 {
  flex: 1;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.d3 {
  background-color: lightblue;
  margin: 5px;
}

.d1 .d2:first-child .d3:last-child {
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="d1">
  <div class="d2">
    <div class="d3">Test1</div>
    <div class="d3">Test2</div>
  </div>
  <div class="d2">
    <div class="d3">Test3</div>
    <div class="d3">Test4<br>Test4</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `flex-grow` to take up the remaining whitespaces.
In this case, both `d2` will be of the same height.
To answer you question either use `flex-grow` only on `test 2` class or modify your structure so that `test2` and `test4` should part of the same parent.

```css
.d1 {
  display: flex;
}

.d2 {
  flex: 1;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.d3 {
  background-color: lightblue;
  margin: 5px;
  flex-grow: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="d1">
  <div class="d2">
    <div class="d3">Test1</div>
    <div class="d3">Test2</div>
  </div>
  <div class="d2">
    <div class="d3">Test3</div>
    <div class="d3">Test4<br>Test4</div>
  </div>
</div>
```